# Pass variable from one component to another ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am woking on a sample ReactJS application, where I want to pass a variable from one component to another.

```js
class Layout extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {keyword: ''};
    }
    render() {
        return (
                 <div className="wrapper">
                   <Search />
                   <Listing />
                  </div>
        );
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Layout />, app
);
```

In the above code, I want to pass a variable from `<Search />` component to `<Listing />` component.

Comment: What event in `Search` happens at the time you want to pass the variable to `Listing`?

Comment: *very poor formating of code :).* There are different ways to do this redux, events, etc. Little bit more information about your code will be helpful.

Comment: @DavinTryon <search /> component is actually a form with and text input to enter the keyword, I want to pass the variable onSubmit of the form action.

Comment: So, you need an `onSubmit` prop for `Search` and then handle the `onSubmit` in `Layout`.  @Andrew's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with function like

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            keyword: '',
            yourVariable: null
        };
    }
    sendVariable(newValue) {
        this.setState({ yourVariable: newValue });
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <Search onChange={this.sendVariable.bind(this)} />
                <Listing sendValue={this.state.yourVariable} />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

class Search extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let variable = "";
        return <div onClick={this.porps.onChange(variable)}></div>;
    }
}
```

Or use [React-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux).

Answer (score 1):

Rlijo you'd pass props to components as follows:

`<Search paramA={someParam} paramB={anotherParam} />`
and to use the props within the Search component you'd call `this.props.paramA` (if using classes).

The way you've got the components setup, you wouldn't be able to share the state from the Search component (i.e. the object in this.state within Search) with the Listing component. There are libraries such as Redux designed to solve problems of shared state across components.

Props (or variables or params) flow downward so you'd need to provide shared props from a parent component. See you could provide this.state.keyword as a prop to both Search and Listing as these two components sit inside this parent component.